# error is class,interface or enum expected? import relational.compare

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
package relational;

public class compare
{

    public int getMax(int x,int y)
    {
        if(x>y){

            return x;                       
        }

        else{
            return y;

        }

    }
}


import relational.compare;

public class Pack
{

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        int a=7,b=9;
        compare ob=new compare();
        int max=ob.getMax(a,b);

    }


}
```

This won't compile for some reason.
please help me solve this error.
Is the error class-related, interface or enum-related?
the problem seems to be in import `relational.compare`.

Comment: You are declaring a class called *c*ompare, but you are using one called *C*ompare? Is it that?

Comment: The key thing is: given your input, we can't say for sure what your problem is. Either you have two files, then it would be a type between c/Compare; or if you have all stuff in one file ... then that would be really wrong.

Comment: did you work it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issue with this code.

1. If this whole code is in one java file then there cab be only one public class.
2. Change the name of class from "compare" to "Compare" (C in upper case), because object you are making have 'C' in upper case.
3. You have two variables with same name 'a', change any one of them.

After these changes your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that only one class can be public in a file.
you have both compare and pack as public.

try to separate them into 2 files.

OR

do this:

```
package relational;

import relational.Compare;//not really needed at all because they are in the same file

public class Pack {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 7, b = 9;
        Compare ob = new Compare();
        int max = ob.getMax(a, b);

    }

}

class Compare {

    public int getMax(int x, int y) {
        if (x > y) {

            return x;
        }

        else {
            return y;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nonsense. import Pack followed by class Pack.

Comment: whoops XD. my bad